# Function to left shift a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a function within my program to left shift all the numbers in an array that was passed to the function. An example is:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

becomes

```
2 3 4
5 6 1
```

My code is:

```
void LeftShift(int array[][N])/*Get the array from main*/
{
    int r, c, temp;
    for(r = 0; r < M; r++) { //Start at row 0 and add one each time
      for(c = 0; c < N; c++) { //Start at column 0 and add one each time
         if(c > 0) {
            array[r][c] = array[r][c-1]; //Number is moved over one if its not the first column
         }
         else if(c == 0 && r > 0) { //If its first column but not first row
            array[r][c] = array[r-1][N-1];//Move number up one row and too last column
         }
         else {
         temp = array[r][c];//If its first column and first row store value in temp
        }
      }
    }
    array[M-1][N-1] = temp;//Put temp value at end of array
}
```

When I print this out all I get is the first number from the original array in every spot in the array. M is defined at the top to be 6 and N is defined to be 5.  After this runs, I call a function that prints out the new array and all I get is the first value 30 times in an array.

Comment: Well, this `array[r][c] = array[r][c-1]` actually shifts row elements *to the right* (assuming that column indices increase left to right). Yet you said that you wanted to shift to the left. So, why are you shifting to the right when you wanted to shift to the left? Also, since you are processing the row elements in left-to-right direction, this will obviously just fill the whole row with the first value.

Comment: If the `1` that falls off is meant to reappear at the end, then this is called *rotate*, not *shift*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2-D arrays are contiguous in memory, so you can iterate over it as if it were a 1-D array:

```
void left_rotate(int array[][N])
{
    int *flat = (int *)array;
    int temp = flat[0];

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < M*N; ++i )
        flat[i-1] = flat[i];

    flat[M*N-1] = temp;

}
```

The `for` loop could also be replaced with a single block move:

```
memmove(&flat[0], &flat[1], (M*N-1) * sizeof *flat);
```

Comment: So i got it to work using user3386109 suggestion but is your answer more efficient?

Comment: @JackV try it and see if you can measure any difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
array[r][c] = array[r][c-1];
```

should be

```
array[r][c-1] = array[r][c];
```

Likewise for the row shift.

Comment: Wow what a stupid mistake but thanks a lot it works now

Answer (score -1):

You can go throw the array, having a pointer **following** the last place you visited, and moving the elements, as in this example:

```
#define nrows 4
#define ncols 4

int array[nrows][ncols] = {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8, },
    { 9, 10, 11, 12, },
    { 13, 14, 15, 16, },
};

int main()
{
    int row, col;
    int saved_int;
    int *p = &saved_int;

    /* rotate elements */
    for(row = 0; row < nrows; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < ncols; col++) {
            *p = array[row][col];
            p = &array[row][col];
        } /* for */
    *p = saved_int;

    /* print matrix */
    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
            printf( "%s%d",
                    (col ? "\t" : ""),
                    array[row][col]);
        printf("\n");
    } /* for */
    return 0;
} /* main */
```

Comment: some comment to the down vote would be appreciated, as I have dedicated some time to try to help by probing it before posting.