# Applying a left shift in C

Tags: c

I am learning how to manipulate a 2D array in C and I have to apply a left shift to a matrix, so A[0][0] becomes the value at A[0][1] etc. This is the code and output that I got after a few tries; I think I may be getting close:

```
void LeftShift2D(int A[M][N]){
int i;
int j;
int temp;
for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
        temp = A[0][0];
        A[i][j] = A[i+1][j+1];
    }
}
A[i][j] = temp;
}
```

Given this as the input:

```
14 17 28 26 24
26 17 13 10 2
3 8 21 20 24
17 1 7 23 17
12 9 28 10 3
21 3 14 8 26
```

this is the desired output:

```
17 28 26 24 26
17 13 10 2 3
8 21 20 24 17
1 7 23 17 12
9 28 10 3 21
3 14 8 26 14
```

but this is the actual output I'm getting:

```
14 17 28 26 24 
26 17 13 10 2 
3 8 21 20 24 
17 1 7 23 17 
12 9 28 10 3 
21 3 14 8 26 
4
17 13 10 2 3 
8 21 20 24 17 
1 7 23 17 12 
9 28 10 3 21 
3 14 8 26 4 
-1218716075 -1217196044 0 -1079502888 134514340
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `so A[0][0] becomes the value at A[1][0]` I'm thinking you mean `A[0][1]`? Can you more clearly format the original array, the output you're getting, and the expected output? (And maybe add the code you used to print the arrays?)

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as this question from last week, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334143/function-to-left-shift-a-2d-array-in-c/

Comment: @MattMcNabb: the objective is the same; the bugs in the posted code are, not surprisingly, different.  The suggested/accepted solution in both is essentially the same (this one is neater in that it avoids an unnecessary cast).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the cast is actually necessary - your code causes undefined behaviour by accessing out of bounds of `A[0]` .  By doing `(int *)A` or `(int *)&A` the pointer is bounded to `A` rather than `A[0]`.   I didn't comment yet as I wanted to link to further reading instead of having an argument in comments; there are other SO posts on this topic but I can't find them (hurrah for SO's search feature)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Come again? `A[0][0]` is out of bounds how?  And `&A[0][0]` is out of bounds how?  In any valid 2D array, that is the one element that's guaranteed to exist, isn't it? The matrix is laid out with contiguous memory. I really look forward to a detailed analysis of what you consider is wrong with my code that is fixed by a cast.  If need be (it is too long), you can email it to me; see my profile.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `A[0][0]` is fine but when you have iterated `N` times you will read off the end of the array `A[0]` . It's the same reason that `A[0][N]` is not permitted.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: and how does the cast make a difference?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler using `&A` or `A` means we are iterating over the object `A`, not over the object `A[0]`. The cast is required because `&A` or `A` have different type to `int *` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I really don't see the difference.  It means we're going to have to agree to disagree.  `&A[0][0]` is an `int *` with the same value as the cast pointers, but without the cast.  The cast does nothing except quiet the compiler; it does not change the fundamentals.

Comment: a comparative scenario would be `struct { int A[3]; int B; } s; assert(sizeof(s) == 4*sizeof(int));` then try to work with `A[3]`. Although we know that `B` is in the location where `A[3]` would be , the rules about pointer arithmetic disallow it. The rationale for these rules is to permit bounds-checking implementations; for debugging/QA purposes a pointer may be checked against the bounds of the object it was assigned to point to. (sometimes called "fat pointer" - the value of the pointer includes info about the object it's pointing to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
void LeftShift2D(int A[M][N])
{
    int i;
    int temp = A[0][0];
    int *base = &A[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < M * N - 1; i++)
        base[i] = base[i+1];
    A[i] = temp;
}
```

This treats the array as a vector and shifts the data down one space, rotating the value originally at the start to the end.  If you wanted to rotate each row separately, you'd use different code, more closely related to what you show:

```
void LeftShift2D(int A[M][N])
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        int j;
        int temp = A[i][0]
        for (j = 0; j < N - 1; j++)
            A[i][j] = A[i][j+1];
        A[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Your code has various problems.  The `A[i][j] = A[i+1][j+1];` assignment accesses data out of bounds, and copies data 'diagonally', copying the cell to the bottom-right (or south-east) of the current cell, not the cell to the right (east) of the current cell.  It has problems wrapping, too.

Answer (score 1):

You have a buffer overflow here

```
A[i][j] = A[i+1][j+1];
```

you need to iterate to `i < M - 1` and `j < N - 1`.

You are accessing invalid memory which explains the observed values, that also invokes undefined behavior so you could observe some strange behavior eventually.

Comment: Not to mention that's a diagonal move. A left shift would be `a[i][j] = a[i][j+1]`, staying in the same row.